# Why are some files in Network but not in Sources?

Tags: google-chrome, pug, google-chrome-devtools

I, using a Chrome browser, am troubleshooting a node.js web application on a page generated by Jade.

Most of the script files included in the Jade file appear in the Sources tab in Chrome F12, ie under the tree beginning with Top. However, there is one particular script file that I see has been loaded under the Network tab (Chrome F12) but does not appear in the Sources tab.  As a result I am unable to put breakpoints in that script.

That script file was included with a simple `append` to a block. But in the Network tab, it was shown called with a query string parameter of a long number, eg emoji.js?123232323.

What could be happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: You mean `jQuery.append`? I don't know about this particular behavior with `append`, but some libraries (like jQuery) add random query parameters to the URL to prevent caching (the random number makes each URL unique).

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough.  The `append` refers to the Jade command that appends additional stuff to a block in the base template.